# Enable popup on select and url redirect on select control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I  want menu to be in select control, like this

```
<form id="go">
        <select name="URL" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value">
            <option value="">Select option</option>
            <option onclick="openChangePassword()">Change password</option>
            <option value="www.editpersonaldata.com">Edit personal data</option>
            <option value="www.dashboard.com">Dashboard</option>

        </select>
    </form>
```

This is changing url not a problem, but i have problem with some option because values are calling function, onclick="openChangePassword() and it is not working this way, any solution.
On some option i need url redirect on other i need function call?

Comment: Use the onchange event of SELECT and code logic by filtering regarding SELECT current value. You can't bind event to OPTION in a cross browser way

Answer (score 0):

As A. Wolff points out in his comment, you should add an event listener to the `<select>` element instead. Like this:

```
<form id="go">
    <select name="URL">
        <option value="">Select option</option>
        <option value="openChangePassword">Change password</option>
        <option value="www.editpersonaldata.com">Edit personal data</option>
        <option value="www.dashboard.com">Dashboard</option>

    </select>
</form>
<script>
document.querySelector('select[name="URL"]').addEventListener('change', function(e){
    var selection = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    if(selection == 'openChangePassword'){
        openChangePassword();
    } else {
        window.location.href = selection;
    }
});
</script>
```

Notice that I only use the `value` attribute of `<option>` and then decide what to do in the listener callback function.